# rack-openid: identifier_url changes between deploys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openid, google-openid

I've implemented the OpenID in our Rails app following the instructions found [here](http://blog.sethladd.com/2010/09/ruby-rails-openid-and-google.html). It mostly works, but occasionally I get different responses for `identifier_url` from Google. This causes a duplicate key error when the SessionsController tries to insert a new record for an existing email address with an "old" `identifier_url`. I end up having to delete the existing entry, ask the user to re-register.

The `identifier_url` seems to be a hash, so apparently something in my app has changed, causing Google to generate a new hash. It seems to happen occasionally when I re-deploy my app, perhaps because Capistrano is cleaning up sessions/cookies as part of the deploy process.

What goes into the creation of the `identifier_url`, and how can I configure OpenID to generate them consistently?